# Android Bitmap pixels become slightly rectangular for larger width/height ratios

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am working on a pixel art editor for Android, and I noticed that when I create Bitmaps with more obscure width/height ratios, for example 3x300 or 5x90 (or the other way round) the pixels become **slightly rectangular**.

I've tried for a week or two to find out what exactly I am doing 'wrong' with the sizing calculations, but I have no idea how to fix this issue. This issue is not recreatable when creating Bitmaps with similar width/height ratios, for example a 50x40 or 90x80.

Below is the code that handles the sizing of the Rect in which we draw the Bitmap on.

Since some people had issues understanding the code, I will try to explain it. First of all, the ratio gives us the scaling factor in which we should multiply the base width/height so that our bitmap appears as expected.

For example, let's say the user selected a 5x10 (width is 5, and height is 10) bitmap, the height is larger than the width so the ratio will be 5/10 which is 0.5. now, the width remains the same, all we need to really scale is the height, so we take the height of the container and multiply that by 0.5 to get our desired result, et cetera. This is my best effort at explaining how the view is sized.

```
private fun setBoundingRect() {
    val ratio = if (bitmapWidth > bitmapHeight) {
        bitmapHeight.toDouble() / bitmapWidth.toDouble()
    } else {
        bitmapWidth.toDouble() / bitmapHeight.toDouble()
    }

    val rectW: Int = if (bitmapWidth > bitmapHeight) {
        width
    } else if (bitmapHeight > bitmapWidth) {
        (height * ratio).toInt()
    } else {
        width
    }

    val rectH: Int = if (bitmapWidth > bitmapHeight)  {
        (width * ratio).toInt()
    } else if (bitmapHeight > bitmapWidth) {
        height
    } else {
        width
    }

    val canvasCenter = Point(width / 2, height / 2)

    val left = canvasCenter.x - rectW / 2
    val top = canvasCenter.y - rectH / 2
    val right = canvasCenter.x + rectW / 2
    val bottom = canvasCenter.y + rectH / 2

    boundingRect = Rect(left, top, right, bottom)
}
```

For the most part, it works well.

`onDraw` method:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    if (::drawingViewBitmap.isInitialized) {
        canvas.drawRect(boundingRect, PaintData.rectPaint)
        canvas.drawBitmap(drawingViewBitmap, null, boundingRect, null)
        drawGrid(canvas)
    }
}
```

Below is a demo of a 3x150 project, and as you can see, the pixels are 'rectangular', and it is quite evident:

[image]

I've tried to figure out what exactly I am doing wrong in my sizing calculations, which I think is where the issue is stemming from, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Full code: https://github.com/therealbluepandabear/RevampedPixelGridView

Comment: Pixels frequently are slightly rectangular.  There's no rule that hdpi and vdpi have to be the same.

Comment: @GabeSechan Then why can't I create the issue in other apps like Aseprite?

Comment: @GabeSechan Sir, it is just calculating how the Rect should be sized within the view according to the specific width/height the user has given... what should I be doing if it is wrong?

Comment: Sorry deleted my pprevious comment because I realized I confused bitmapWidth and Width (I assume width is view width and bitmap width is the image width).  So the bottom half is then centering the bitmap within the stage.  But I'm not sure what the scaling is supposed to accomplish.  What's the top half calculating rectH and rectW supposed to do?

Comment: @GabeSechan it's just calculating how the Rect should be scaled according to the width/height the user has given. It calculates the ratio first and then uses the ratio to calculate the Rect width/height. It works most of the time, it's just the rectangular pixel issue is bugging me.

Comment: canvasCenter.x - rectW / 2   should be (canvasCenter.x - rectW) / 2.  Same for the other 3 lines

Comment: @GabeSechan as I have told you, that breaks everything. I believe that part of calculation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio of your `Rect` varies depending the AR of the bitmap, but also on the size and aspect ratio of your `View` ([runnable example](https://pl.kotl.in/WaDlGKopT)):

```
calculated rect width as 16 px, actual 16.62
View size: 876 x 831
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.019277109

calculated rect width as 19 px, actual 19.16
View size: 887 x 958
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.018789144

calculated rect width as 19 px, actual 19.96
View size: 888 x 998
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.018036073

calculated rect width as 17 px, actual 17.26
View size: 936 x 863
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.018561484
```

So your `Rect`'s aspect ratio can be out by as much as 10% compared to the original bitmap at these `View` size - much more if the `View` is smaller.

---

It's happening because you're relying on integer rounding to calculate the short dimension (those `calculated rect width`s up there are the result of `toInt()` on the `actual` float calculations). That introduces some error, and because the values you're working with are so small that becomes significant.

You could improve it just by using `roundToInt()` instead of `toInt()`, so it can at least hit the closest integer every time:

```
calculated rect width as 18 px, actual 17.900000000000002
View size: 900 x 895
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.020134227

calculated rect width as 18 px, actual 18.080000000000002
View size: 943 x 904
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.019911505

calculated rect width as 19 px, actual 19.080000000000002
View size: 923 x 954
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.018867925

calculated rect width as 20 px, actual 19.68
View size: 981 x 984
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.020325202
```

---

Or use floating-point calculations and create a `RectF` instead (there are [`drawBitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint)) and [`drawRect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawRect(android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint)) calls that use them):

```
fun setBoundingRect() {    
    val rectW =
        if (bitmapWidth > bitmapHeight) width.toFloat()
        else (bitmapWidth.toFloat() / bitmapHeight) * height
    
    val rectH =
        if (bitmapHeight > bitmapWidth) height.toFloat()
        else (bitmapHeight.toFloat() / bitmapWidth) * width
    
    
    val canvasCenter = Point(width / 2, height / 2)

    val left = canvasCenter.x - rectW / 2
    val top = canvasCenter.y - rectH / 2
    val right = canvasCenter.x + rectW / 2
    val bottom = canvasCenter.y + rectH / 2

    boundingRect = RectF(left, top, right, bottom)
}
```

```
View size: 819 x 897
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.020000003

View size: 987 x 996
Bitmap W/H ratio: 0.02
Rect W/H ratio: 0.019999983
```

Or you could calculate a more appropriate height/width instead of just using the full `height` or `width` of the `View`, so that when you multiply it by `ratio` you get a round number (or close to it) for the other dimension. Right now the accuracy is just down to coincidence, how well the numbers match up